# Strange error when upgrading play-services-auth from 15.0.0 to 16.0.1

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

For my android project I upgraded play-services-auth library version from 15.0.0 to 16.0.1

Since then I see following error during the build and it also produces
`ajcore` files

I have removed my .gradle caches and done build and still see this error.

Anybody else seen this before, how do I fix it?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting .,<, or ;, but found authapi while unpacking Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/internal/BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl;
>       at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:204)
>       at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(GenericSignatureParser.java:155)
>       at org.aspectj.util.GenericSignatureParser.parseTypeArgument(GenericSignatureParser.java:267)

Comment: Do you find solution?

Comment: No I didn't find solution.

Comment: Ok. I think that problem don't have one solution. I investigated this problem and in my case the problematic library was "Let" lib for android permissions -> https://github.com/canelmas/let. When I removed and changed it, the problem  disappeared. Maybe you use this lib? If no, you should check yours all lib.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing the Hugo logging plugin fixed the issue.

Check in your gradle file if you have it configured.

```
classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because some plugin (added by you) use libs:
`org.aspectj:aspectjtools`
or 
`org.aspectj:aspectjrt` for codegeneration